# Partial Search in elastic search failed in test

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data

now when i use partial search query like :

```
QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*" + query + "*").lenient(true).
  field("id").
  field("nameAr").
  field("nameEn").
  field("authorType").
  field("active"));
```

it works when I typed part of any field 
but it fails in generated test class :

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(author.getId().intValue())))
```

it said that can not pars *id:1* and i know the reason ... 
so what is the best way to search partial and success in both browser and test .

Comment: Sorry but I tried to read your question like 15 times, and I cannot understand what your problem is. You may want to reformulate if you want someone to be able to answer.